# Are my cat and kitten fighting or playing?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, aggression, multi-pet-families

I have a new 7 week old kitten and a 1 year old cat. My cat has come to the point where she will clean my kitten (when he lets her) and plays with him. My kitten has not been neutered yet. When they play their tails are either up or aligned with their body (straight) and their ears are generally faced forward. They don't actively seek each other out but they also don't play or attack every time they see each other.  Sometimes they seem to play too rough and one of them squeaks or meows or hisses, but this doesn't happen often. How do I tell if they are fighting or playing? I don't want to discourage them from playing if I view it as fighting.

Answer (score 1):

It's playing. You'll know when it's not. It's completely different. Ears will be back, eyes wide open, loud screaming noises, chunks of fur left behind (or stuck in their claws or mouth).

Especially if they groom each other at other times, they aren't enemies. If they didn't like each other, they definitely wouldn't be doing that, or even get within a foot of each other. And with one being so young, I don't think they would even be like that to each other yet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they’re doing both!

A kitten will learn from an older cat like we all do in any species. Skills like being able to defend itself, hunt, kill a prey, social order and so on....
These play times build the foundation for your cat’s adult health.

If they are grooming each other then all is well. However, at one point your kitten will come to an adult age and will want to mate with your older cat.

This could cause serious problems. Neutering is the best way.  Be aware that hormones for reproduction stay in your neutered cat for a while.

Believe me, when cats fight for real, you’ll know! It doesn’t last long!